# take a main avatar pictute from fb acount link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have array with site users, they indicated url to their fb acounts. And I wanna to show their pics. So I make simple thing like :

```
  $scope.pleaseCheckPics = function (url) {
    if(url) {
      var id = url.split('id=')[1];
      if(id) {
        var link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?type=large';
        return link;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

I give link to `pleaseCheckPics(link)` and it returned pic. But I have a small problem - I need links to fb accounts with ID in URL, but often url looks like : https://www.facebook.com/BobMarley (name or nickname instead id), and my script isn't works. How can I take users pics by acount link in other way?

Comment: You can’t. The `username` field has been removed from the API. But your app should not be dealing with arbitrary profile URLs in the first place. Make users login to your app, then you get their app-scoped user id, and that is all you need.

Comment: @CBroe It's sad, but thx anyway)